# How can I append a string to the data from a form field

Tags: php

I have a form and I need a way of ensuring that only people with a particular email address can successfully signup. For example the only users allowed are from foo.com, so every email address should be like myemail@foo.com. Now I want the user to only have to enter the email user name and after the form is submitted I add the @foo.com using php. How would I go about implementing such a feature and if there is a better way to achieve the desired result where can I find such information . Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You have to put atleast some effort to solve your own problem, before others are willing to help. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @dparoli clearshot helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, name the form field username for example. Name your submit button submit for example

then on form submit

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$username .= "@foo.com"   // jacksperro@foo.com

// rest of your code
}
```

On a note, I'd put a label after the input box saying '@foo.com' to let them know to only type their username

Answer (score 0):

This is basic string concatenation.

```
$suffix = '@foo.com';
$username = 'test';
$email = $username . $suffix;
```

Comment: I wanted to be able to get the input that was typed into a text field from my form

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should do what you need and more:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$user       = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])); // a bit of security
$final_user = sprintf("%s@foo.com", $user);   // user@foo.com

echo $final_user;

}

?>
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.